# SQL (oracle) to compare two lists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a column containing a list (yes I know this violates normalization). I'm trying to find some sore of "overlap" function i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 'a,b,c' OVERLAP TABLE.LISTCOLUMN
```

So, `LISTCOLUMN`contains any or all of a, b, or c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

Use [`regexp_like`](http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html), if you're using Oracle 10g or above:

```
select *
  from my_table
 where regexp_like(listcolumn, '[abc]')
```

This matches everything from your table where `a` *or* `b` *or* `c` is in the column.

Alternatively you can do the more horrible and difficult to maintain:

```
select *
  from my_table
 where listcolumn like '%a%'
    or listcolumn like '%b%'
    or listcolumn like '%c%'
```

#### Here's a little [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12ba6/3) to demonstrate.

However, as you already know, normalising your database properly will save you a lot of pain in the longer run.

Comment: Yeah I went ahead and normalized it rather than kicking the can down the road.

Answer (score -1):

You mean like:

Select * 
from TABLE1 
where LISTCOLUMN in ('a','b','c')

Comment: Yes but then my query wil work. The IN command specifiecies that a value should be a, b or c or any combination.