# How to apply filter on comma separated values in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run the below query I get 3 rows instead of 4,

```
SELECT *
FROM freelook
WHERE done_type IN ('14','27','28')
```

Because in 1 row the value is like this `1,14,27`.This is the comma separated single value in one column.Like this I have many rows which have comma separated value for `done_type`.

I want it should separate the values and then check if it matches the given values.

My query is how to apply filter on such row where value is string which is comma separated value.
Please guide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL (oracle) to compare two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269027/sql-oracle-to-compare-two-lists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search for, say, 14 you could:

```
...
WHERE
    done_type = '14'
    OR done_type LIKE '14,%'
    OR done_type LIKE '%,14'
    OR done_type LIKE '%,14,%'
```

Rinse and repeat for 27, 28 and any other number you want to search for...

This will, however, perform horribly (full table scan).

Instead of putting paint on rust, better to cure the underlying problem<sup>1</sup> and normalize the data by splitting to two tables.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Of violating the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF#Atomicity) and therefore the 1NF.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following SQL (assuming "id" is your PK column).

```
WITH tokens as (
SELECT distinct id, token
FROM        
(SELECT  
id,
SUBSTR (csv,
  INSTR (csv, ',', 1, LEVEL  ) + 1,
  INSTR (csv, ',', 1, LEVEL+1) - INSTR (csv, ',', 1, LEVEL) -1 
  ) AS token
FROM (
  SELECT  id, ','||trim(done_type||',') csv FROM freelook) 
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(csv)-LENGTH(REPLACE(csv,',',''))+1)
  WHERE token is not NULL)

SELECT id FROM tokens
WHERE token in ('14','27','28')
ORDER BY id, token
```

Comment: This is inefficient of course, but if your table is big you can always make the tokenization into a MV.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for one of those values:
Using LIKE:

```
 SELECT *
FROM freelook
WHERE done_type LiKE '%14%'
OR done_type LiKE '%27%'
OR done_type LiKE '%28%'
```

USING REGEX:

```
 SELECT *
FROM freelook
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(done_type, '[^14,|,14,|,14$|^27,|,27,|,27$|^28,|,28,|,28$|]')
```

if you are looking for full match:

USING REGEX:

```
 SELECT *
FROM freelook
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(done_type, '^14,27,28$')
```

EDIT:
 Regex update

Comment: I guess this will be return rows which has values like 114,127 as it has 14 and 27.?

Comment: one should note that the first two also find anything having the search codes embedded, e.g X14X

Comment: Correct just also add commas:) and I think if you are not sure which one is the first value you need to use both: '14,',',14' and ',14,':)

Comment: @HRgiger, Actually this will return `41` as well and it depends if there are columns at the beginning or end... This should be: `(^|,)(14|27|28)($|,)`