# Oracle: Check if number column contains a value from a formatted string of numbers

Tags: database, string, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In my local table, I am try to check if an Oracle Number column called JOBNUMBER has a value that exists in a string parameter. Technically I am passing in the string as a stored procedure nvarchar2 parameter, but for simplicity, I hardcoded the string in my Query below:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, JOB_NUMBER
FROM JOBTABLE
WHERE TO_CHAR(JOB_NUMBER) IN ('00052, 00048');
```

When Oracle runs the query above, it returns no values even though 00052 is a number value in the table column for JOB_NUMBER. I'm thinking that it checks for the whole string ('00052, 00048') in JOB_NUMBER and can't find it, so it returns no values. The string will contain different values each time, and there will several numbers (of type string) in that string.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Which datatype is used for column `JOB_NUMBER`?

Comment: Obviously `SELECT FIRST_NAME, JOB_NUMBER FROM JOBTABLE
WHERE TO_CHAR(JOB_NUMBER) IN ('00052', '00048')`

Comment: What you want is to check if the job number is `in('00052', '00048') - a list of two different strings. What you are passing in is one long string. Do you understand now why that doesn't work? Then: do you really have spaces after the commas in the string parameter? That's odd. Then - someone else just posted almost the same question this morning; look around, I explained the standard way to solve this problem in that thread.

Comment: Even if I didn't have the space, I want to search one long string for the number. Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply filter on comma separated values in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349183/how-to-apply-filter-on-comma-separated-values-in-oracle)

Comment: No it's not a duplicate...My commas are in the string; it doesn't separate several string. I simply have one long string...

Comment: @DrewNewman still you can use that approach to parse your comma-separated string into a set of values, with which you can then simply join your original table. Make sure you cast them to `NUMBER`s after parsing.

Comment: @mustaccio can you provide an example of what you mean? Keep in mind the number of values in my string can differ per query execution.

Comment: It's right there in the "duplicate" answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12352254/1227152

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to keep the leading zeroes of the number when comparing to the string, then looping through the string to compare.  Here a CTE is used is to simulate creating a numeric job number and a string to search.  The TO_CHAR function makes sure to preserve the leading zeroes and the FM format removes the leading space that TO_CHAR leaves for the sign.  CONNECT BY loops through the elements for the count of the delimiter + 1 times, keeping the count in the value in 'LEVEL'. This value is used in REGEXP_SUBSTR to iterate through the elements to compare the converted numeric value to each element to see if a match is found.  Note this regular expression allows for NULL elements should you need to know which item in the list is your match.

```
SQL> with tbl(job_nbr_in, job_str_in) as (
     select 00052, '00052, 00048' from dual
   )
   select --level element_nbr,
          to_char(job_nbr_in, 'FM00000') search_for, job_str_in in_string,
          regexp_substr(job_str_in, '(.*?)(, |$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) found
   from tbl
   where to_char(job_nbr_in, 'FM00000') = regexp_substr(job_str_in, '(.*?)(, |$)', 1, level, NULL, 1)
   connect by level <= regexp_count(job_str_in, ',')+1;

SEARCH_FOR IN_STRING    FOUND
---------- ------------ ------------
00052      00052, 00048 00052
```

If you are not sure if you will always have a space after the comma, remove spaces with REPLACE and adjust the delimiter in REGEXP_SUBSTR:

```
with tbl(job_nbr_in, job_str_in) as (
  select 00052, '00052, 00048' from dual
)
select to_char(job_nbr_in, 'FM00000') search_for, job_str_in in_string,
       regexp_substr(replace(job_str_in, ' '), '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) found
from tbl
where to_char(job_nbr_in, 'FM00000') = regexp_substr(replace(job_str_in, ' '), '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1)
connect by level <= regexp_count(job_str_in, ',')+1;
```